# MongoDB find filtered by attributes in an array

Tags: mongodb

I have inherited a collection containing documents similar to the one below. I want to find all documents where the CreatedDate Value.Date is (say) "2014-11-29" and EquipmentCategory Value.Text.@id is "M".

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55deebb1f7db2e09184e1126"),
"ns0:Equipment" : {
    "EquipmentNo" : "98031047",
    "EquipmentDescription" : "Machine X",
    "SerialNo" : "EX87GA",
    "Attributes" : {
        "Attribute" : [ 
            {
                "Name" : "CreatedDate",
                "Values" : {
                    "Value" : {
                        "Date" : "2014-11-29"
                    }
                }
            }, 
            {
                "Name" : "CreatedBy",
                "Values" : {
                    "Value" : {
                        "Text" : "MEE903070"
                    }
                }
            }, 
            {
                "Name" : "EquipmentCategory",
                "Values" : {
                    "Value" : {
                        "Text" : {
                            "@id" : "M",
                            "#text" : "Machines"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
}
```

I'm looking for a MongoDB shell or C# query that can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to a query that matches multiple fields within the *same* array element is to use the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) operator. Then, because you need to match two separate element condition combinations within the same array, you need to use [`$and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and) to combine them:

```js
db.test.find({$and: [{
        'ns0:Equipment.Attributes.Attribute': {
            $elemMatch: {
                Name: 'CreatedDate',
                'Values.Value.Date': '2014-11-29'
            }
        }
    }, {
        'ns0:Equipment.Attributes.Attribute': {
            $elemMatch: {
                Name: 'EquipmentCategory',
                'Values.Value.Text.@id': 'M'
            }
        }
    }]
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Next question though is, is it possible to index this collection to make that query efficient?

Comment: @swiftyd Glad it worked for you, and welcome to SO. Regarding your next question: Yes, but do some research first and then come back and post a new question if you still need help.